# UIActivityViewController and ALAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a task to share video from Assets Library to Vimeo. I'm implementing activity controller this way:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[_videoAsset.defaultRepresentation.url];

UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                      initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
activity.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypeMessage,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,
                                   ];

[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Apple documentation says that I can share my ALAsset or URL as activity item, but I have only "Save Video" option in controller. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you setup your Vimeo account in the Settings app?

Comment: No. But should I do it? Facebook & Twitter appears in control even if my account is not set.

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, really I just needed to set up account. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too, eventually managed to share after saving ALAsset's data as a file and sharing it.

The code looks like this:

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [assetsLibrary assetForURL:videoUrl resultBlock: ^(ALAsset *asset){
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
        NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* videoPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"VIDEO.MOV"];

        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:videoPath error:&error];
        BOOL success = [data writeToFile:videoPath atomically:YES];
        if (success) {
            NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath], nil];

            UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
            [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }


    } failureBlock:nil];
```